# Coredata NSPredicate with subquery

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

I need to search for Houses within a certain latitude and longitude area. I also need these houses to have at least one relationship with Object A where object A needs to have at least one relationship with Object B.

The below predicate format seems to be very slow at returning results:

```
@"latitude > %@ AND latitude < %@ AND longitude > %@ AND longitude < %@ AND (SUBQUERY(as, $a, ANY $a.bs != NULL).@count > 0)"
```

The below predicate format returns results quick, but I have to have code to manually check the relations to A, and also the relationship to B for each A, if any:

```
@"latitude > %@ AND latitude < %@ AND longitude > %@ AND longitude < %@"
```

My question therefore is, when I have multiple conditions joined by AND, does the Coredata search evaluate each condition even if one has failed / is not true? It just seems as if the former predicate takes too long.

Comment: Or is there a more efficient way to do this?